# PKPassLibraryDidChangeNotification when the app is in background(iOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, passbook, passkit

Is it possible to receive PKPassLibraryDidChangeNotification when my app is in background?

For instance, if my coupon rewards changes(by scanning the QR code) my app has to update its database with the changed reward even if it is in background. I think its possible, if some thread is listening to PKPassLibraryDidChangeNotification forever in the background but apple doesn't encourage to run a task in background forever.

So any other alternate suggestions to achieve this?

Comment: Could you not push an update directly to the app at the same time you're pushing an update to the card?

Comment: When you scan the QR code it will take to the update URL of the coupon which is embedded automatically by Passkit, so i don't have control over that update URL. So thats not possible i guess. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: I don't understand. What is scanning the QR code?

Comment: The update to the coupon is done by passkit automatically and it will push the notification to passbook. So I don't have control over that push notification, its done automatically. Thats wat I am trying to say.